# Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)'))

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using the requests library in python and keep observing some funny behavior. I am running my code in a docker container in AWS ECS and get the below error when using the request call without a proxy:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.foo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /foo/JMD87FHD6GA068ZD9SS (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

When I set a proxy for the request, (in this case using a residential based proxy), I no longer get the error. This has been consistent and I can't figure out what would cause this. I'd be happy if anyone could even just point me in the right investigative direction (most related posts are old and refer to python libraries that are very out of date).

I've tried both EC2 and Fargate for running the task and get the same results.

More information about my setup:

Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# machine requirements
RUN apk --no-cache update
RUN apk --no-cache add python3-dev gcc libc-dev libffi-dev bash

# project requirements
COPY ./requirements ./requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/pip-tools.txt
RUN pip-sync requirements/prod.txt --pip-args '--no-cache-dir'
```

Contents of requirements/prod.txt

```
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with python 3.10
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements/prod.in
#
anyio==3.6.1
    # via
    #   starlette
    #   watchfiles
bcrypt==4.0.0
    # via passlib
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
    # via -r requirements/base.in
certifi==2022.6.15
    # via
    #   elasticsearch
    #   requests
cffi==1.15.0
    # via cryptography
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
    # via requests
click==8.1.3
    # via uvicorn
cloudscraper==1.2.66
    # via -r requirements/base.in
cryptography==37.0.2
    # via
    #   pymysql
    #   python-jose
dependency-injector==4.39.1
    # via -r requirements/base.in
dnspython==2.2.1
    # via email-validator
ecdsa==0.18.0
    # via python-jose
elasticsearch==7.13.4
    # via -r requirements/base.in
email-validator==1.3.0
    # via fastapi
fastapi[all]==0.85.0
    # via -r requirements/base.in
h11==0.14.0
    # via uvicorn
httptools==0.5.0
    # via uvicorn
idna==3.3
    # via
    #   anyio
    #   email-validator
    #   requests
itsdangerous==2.1.2
    # via fastapi
jinja2==3.1.2
    # via fastapi
markupsafe==2.1.1
    # via jinja2
orjson==3.8.0
    # via fastapi
passlib[bcrypt]==1.7.4
    # via -r requirements/base.in
pyasn1==0.4.8
    # via
    #   python-jose
    #   rsa
pycparser==2.21
    # via cffi
pydantic==1.10.2
    # via fastapi
pymysql[rsa]==1.0.2
    # via -r requirements/base.in
pyparsing==3.0.9
    # via cloudscraper
python-dotenv==0.21.0
    # via uvicorn
python-jose[cryptography]==3.3.0
    # via -r requirements/base.in
python-multipart==0.0.5
    # via fastapi
pyyaml==6.0
    # via
    #   fastapi
    #   uvicorn
requests==2.28.1
    # via
    #   cloudscraper
    #   fastapi
    #   requests-toolbelt
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
    # via cloudscraper
rsa==4.9
    # via python-jose
six==1.16.0
    # via
    #   dependency-injector
    #   ecdsa
    #   python-multipart
    #   user-agent
sniffio==1.3.0
    # via anyio
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
    # via beautifulsoup4
starlette==0.20.4
    # via fastapi
tqdm==4.63.0
    # via -r requirements/base.in
typing-extensions==4.3.0
    # via pydantic
ujson==5.5.0
    # via fastapi
urllib3==1.26.12
    # via
    #   elasticsearch
    #   requests
user-agent==0.1.10
    # via -r requirements/base.in
uvicorn[standard]==0.18.3
    # via
    #   -r requirements/base.in
    #   fastapi
uvloop==0.17.0
    # via uvicorn
watchfiles==0.17.0
    # via uvicorn
websockets==10.3
    # via uvicorn
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I am speculating a little, but someone else may have a similar issue who lands on this question after a google search.

Maybe you are sending multiple requests in your code (*say in a multi-threaded fashion*). That's tripping a wire somewhere along the chain.

Maybe the proxy is regulating the number of outbound requests, and hence you don't get an error.